# Apache Set Environment Variable from received nginx proxy_set_header

Tags: apache

Assume I have an nginx config like:

```
proxy_set_header ENVIRONMENT testing;  ## dynamically created based on a check
proxy_pass apache;
```

Now I want apache to receive the content of the header `ENVIRONMENT` (I think apache renames it to `HTTP_ENVIRONMENT`) and then I want to store it into an environment variable called `$ENVIRONMENT` of the apache user www-data so that my perl application can read it.

I tried like this:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:%{HTTP_ENVIRONMENT}]
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}e"
SetEnvIf HTTP_ENVIRONMENT "(.*)" ENVIRONMENT=$1
```

from what I have found through apache help pages or other serverfault-questions. SetEnv does not seem to be able to actually set an environment variable with the content of another one. Any other solution to this?

Edit: now that's my current try:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:%{HTTP:ENVIRONMENT}]
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}"
PassEnv ENVIRONMENT
Header set X-ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}e"
```

Comment: did  you check `%{HTTP:ENVIRONMENT}` ?

Comment: err, to which directive belongs that? RewriteRule or SetEnvIf?

Comment: that is what I currently have:

RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:%{HTTP:ENVIRONMENT}]
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}"
PassEnv ENVIRONMENT
Header set X-ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}e"

Comment: but it does not set the variable, it just sets the string:
# curl -I localhost  --->     X-ENVIRONMENT: %{ENVIRONMENT}

Comment: All incoming http-headers are available in all Apache expressions through the `%{HTTP:header}`. Only standart headers are accessible via HTTP_*.

Comment: ok, available are they, but how do I get the value into an environment variable?

Comment: seems neither `SetEnv` nor `SetEnvIf` supports expressions unlike the `RewriteRule`. Tested with `RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENVIRONMENT:%{HTTP:Host}]`.

Comment: exactly. SetEnv does not seem to work with variables or expressions. But it must be possible anyway. I cant be the only one ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it works:

nginx.conf:

```
proxy_set_header ENVIRONMENT "test";
```

apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=ENVIRONMENT:%{HTTP:ENVIRONMENT}]
```

to check it back:

apache:

```
Header set ENVIRONMENT "%{ENVIRONMENT}e"
```

My fault was, that I thought I could see the environment variable on the system of user www-data with `env`, but the environment variable is anyhow within the apache thread and not being visible on the system.